# How can i update my lisbox using ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

How can i create an ajax in my search when i select a country it would show me all states that i have in the country selected

I'm trying to create a display when i select country automatically show all the states that has the country selected

My tables

```
Countries

  |id| |country_name|
   1    'USA'
   2     'Peru'

States

   |id| |state_name|
    1      Alabama
    2      Machupicchu

Country_States
    |id|  |country_id|   |state_id|
     1       1              1
     2       2              2
```

My controller

```
 class Country_StatesController < ApplicationController
  def conditional

    @countries = Country.find(:all)
    @states= State.find(:all)

    @selected_country = Country.find_by_id(params[:countries])  if params[:countries].to_i
    @selected_state = State.find_by_id(params[:states])  if params[:states].to_i
    @search= CountryState.find(:all,:conditions=> ['state_id','country_id' ],params[:states],params[:countries] )
  end
 end
```

My view

```
<% form_tag :controller=>"country_States",:action=>"conditional" do %>

    <%= select_tag "countries", options_for_select(@countries.collect {|t| [t.state_name.to_s ,t.id]})  %>

    <%= select_tag "states", options_for_select(@states.collect {|t| [t.state_name.to_s ,t.id]}, params[:search].to_i ) %>

    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

I found something like this

```
  <%= collection_select :selection, :level, User::LEVELS, :to_s, :to_s, {},
     {:onchange => remote_function(
      :url => {:action => "updatelevel", :controller => "user", :id=> user.id},
      :with => "'level_id='+this.value"
    )
  }
  %>
```

I will appreciate help.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to make `states` belong_to a `country` then just list `country.states`?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: My assosiation is done...but you didn't answer my principal question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all the states belonging to a given country first set up the following relationship:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
end
```

Then in the controller you can call all states like this:

```
@country = Country.find(params[:id])
@states = @country.states #this will be a hash of all states that belong_to @country
```

and in the view, you can create a list like this (or use a table, depending on how you want it to be formatted):

```
<ul>  
<% @states.each do |state| %>
  <li>
    <%= state.name %>
  </li>
  #etc
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: It worked is like i did but, the ajax should show show all the states that has the country selected ,not all my values,that's what i'm asking

Comment: actually when i read your question again, I think maybe you want this: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories - I should have read more carefully but be a bit more descriptive with your titles and posts in the future

Comment: dax i wanted something like this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox but display states by country

Comment: I still don't find the information about this, do yo have some information?

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple answer here:

```
http://pullmonkey.com/2008/03/30/dynamic-select-boxes-ruby-on-rails/
```

Is very useful and descriptive.